# How to increase an array's element with pointers in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, increment, lvalue

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int array[20]={1,5,10,15,20};
    array[10]=*array+1;
    array[1]=*(array+2)++;
    array[5]=*(array+3)*array[4];
    printf("array[10]=%d\narray[1]= %d\narray[5] = %d\n",array[10], array[1], array[5]);
    return 0;
}
```

I got "Ivalue required as increment operand" error. What can I do to fix my codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this statement

```
array[1]=*(array+2)++;
```

the right hand expression is equivalent to

```
array[1]=*( (array+2)++ );
```

that is at first the postfix increment is applied to the temporary object (pointer) `array + 2` and its result (the pointer before incrementing) is dereferenced.

You may not increment a temporary object. If you mean to post-increment the value of the pointed element then you should write

```
array[1] = ( *(array+2) )++;
```

If you want to pre-increment the value then you should write

```
array[1] = ++*(array+2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i fixed it:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int array[20]={1,5,10,15,20};
    array[10]=*array+1; //This gets the value of array[0] adds 1 and assigns it to array[10]
    array[1]=((*(array+2))++);// This assigns the value of array[2] to array[1] and then increments array[2] by 1
    /****
    int i=0;
    Remember the difference between printf("%d,i++); & printf("%d,++i);
    the first prints the value then increments i by 1
    the second increments the value then print i;
    */
    array[5]=*(array+3)*array[4]; //This is equivalent to array[5] = array[3]*array[4]=15*20=300
    printf("array[10]=%d\narray[1]= %d\narray[5] = %d\narray[2]=%d",array[10], array[1], array[5],array[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

*(array+2)++ mean *(array+2)=*(array+2)+1 and in your case   array[1]=*(array+2)++ which means array[1]=*(array+2)=*(array+2)+1 !!! Error

you should do this :

```
main()
{
  int array[20]={1,5,10,15,20};
  array[10]=*array+1;
  array[1]=*(array+2)+1;
  array[5]=*(array+3)*array[4];
  printf("array[10]=%d\narray[1]= %d\narray[5] = %d\n",array[10], array[1], 
  array[5]);
  return 0;
}
```

or if you want to get the next value :

```
array[1]=*( (array+2)++ );
```